# php poo insert muchos a muchos

Tags: php, poo, insert

Si tengo una relación muchos a muchos: Libros Libros/Autores Autores
Me podrían ayudar con las siguientes preguntas:
Debo crear una clase para cada tabla? incluida la tabla intermedia?
Cómo haría la inserción?

Por favor tienen algún ejemplo funcional?

Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Hola. quizas te interesaria echar un vistazo al [tour] y [ask]

Comment: Pon algo de código que hayas probado, o los intentos que hayas hecho.

Comment: En un ORM como `doctrine`, por ejemplo, no tendrías que mapear la tabla intermedia. Como te ha comentado @vzenix, usa un ORM con el que te encuentres cómodo y no reinventes la rueda.

Comment: @Muriano gracias he usado Eloquent, pero de todas formas me quedo con el gusano de cómo se hará sin usar ORM. Si tienes ejemplo t agradecería mucho me puedas ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Lo he hecho usando el ORM ELOQUENT. si desean las ayudas están:
[Usar ELOQUENT SIN LARAVEL](https://styde.net/implementar-eloquent-orm-en-tu-proyecto-sin-laravel/)

[Manejo de Muchos a Muchos con eloquent](http://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/)

**En todo caso si alguien me podría ayudar con ejemplo sin uso de ORM le agradecería mucho, tengo el gusanito de cómo se hará que no me deja en paz.**